# Copy the sheet with index to a new Workbook

Tags: excel, indexing, copy, vba

I use this code to copy sheets(i) to new workbook but it always error at `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Copy` . If I use specific sheet (like `sheets("Handover")`) code run. Please help me explain what 's wrong

```
Sub CopyToNew()
    'Copy the sheets(i) to a new Workbook.
    For i = 3 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Copy
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 3 or more worksheets, what's happening is that the first time you do `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Copy`, the newly created workbook becomes the `ActiveWorkbook`, with only one worksheet.

To avoid this anomaly, replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook` in your code.

Also, Check if there are *hidden sheets* in the workbook, the method `Copy` fails on hidden worksheets.

Comment: @Luunguyen Check if you have hidden worksheets in your workbook.